# The mysterious "Couldn't not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0..." error

Tags: c#, wcf

Scenario:  I have a WCF endpoint (*endpoint Manufacturing*) that connects another WCF endpoint (*endpoint DataAPIClient*) as ConnectedService.  The constructor of an entity in A instantiate the "client" (see below).  On top of all these, I have a xUnit test project testing A.

```
// Manufacturing constructor
public Manufacturing() {
  client = new DataAPIClient();
}
```

// Instantiating in the xUnit project
   Manufacturing endpoint = new Manufacturing();

Problem: Something changed (and I couldn't figure out what) that when the test project tries to instantiate Manufacturing.  I got this error:

```
Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have verified the System.ServiceModel.dll in both endpoints.  DataAPIClient has 4.0.30319 and manufacturing has 4.0.0.0.

P.S.  I did change the name of the Manufacturing project...not sure if that caused that, but I thought it might be worth of mentioning.

Any help is greatly appreciated...I've been googling and found nothing.

Comment: Does your test project have a reference to System.ServiceModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per howcheng's suggestion, I noticed that since I was using xUnit Test Project (.NET Core), I couldn't (or maybe I just didn't know how) add any reference to System.ServiceModel.dll.  So I created a Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) and added the xUnit Nugets and System.ServiceModel.dll assembly.  The error went away.